# jquery problems with animate

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the text to flip. [My code](http://jsfiddle.net/LJxPz/3/)

```
<div id="text" style="position: absolute">  </div>
```

The text is generated from the javascript into the div above as you can it in my code.

I don't know what I've wrong.

Comment: Please elaborate on the issue. What isn't your code doing that you want it to do?

Comment: You want it to flip how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but I've disabled the `margin-left: -850px` on the header, and I've converted your javascript stuff to equivalent (mostly) CSS animations.  It rotates through the 3 texts instead of going on forever.  Your code was a bit difficult to understand exactly what you were trying to achieve, so I had to make a lot of assumptions on what you wanted your final thing to look like and do.

http://jsfiddle.net/LJxPz/6/

and here is one with a nice cross-fade between the different texts: http://jsfiddle.net/LJxPz/7/

Comment: Well I've to start to use more css and less jquery :) Thanks!

Comment: CSS animations are amazing. See also [SVG animation](http://jsfiddle.net/N9wzH/)

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
.header {
   margin-left: -850px;
}
```

so your code is running outside browser :)

Remove `margin-left: -850px;` and you can see moving text :)

Comment: No, it's still not working! The text will only fade in and out but not move. The Animation-script is correct but there is something wrong the css that disturb.